# What is an exponential graph of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

So According to this [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematician-disproves-hedetniemis-graph-theory-conjecture-20190617/), The exponential graph of a graph $G$ is constructed by first defining a set of colors$\{1,...,n\}$. Then the vertex set of the exponential graph is the set of functions from the vertex set of $G$ to the set of colors. However, they have not given how two vertices are connected in the exponential graph.

Comment: Two different functions $f,g$ are joined by an edge when for all $(x,y)$ in the edges of $G$ one has $f(x)\neq g(y)$. In other words they never associate the same color to vertices that are connected in $G$.

Comment: Does this mean that $f(y) \neq g(x)$ as well?

Comment: Yes, both are different.

Comment: can anyone help us more this does not seem like very detailed explanation , i still need some clarification